# What is the latest Java SDK that can be used for Android app development?

Tags: java, android, macos, java-8, sdk

I recently bought a new MacBook. I installed the Android SDK and Studio and then I imported my project. AS suggested to use the bundled Open JDK for my project. I accepted and I am able to build and run my project via AS.

The problem is, my command line doesn't work :(

```
==> ./gradlew clean
No Java runtime present, requesting install.
```

After running the above code the following alert displays. [This web page](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-downloads.html) will be open when I click on the `More Info` button.

[image: Install java command-line tool]

After I searched I realized that I have to have JDK installed on my laptop. I remember -from thousand years ago- that I have to have JDK 8 on my laptop. I also heard that android projects work with JDK 11.

It looks like the latest JDK is 15. So, what should I do? What is the latest JDK that can be used for Android app development?

Comment: anything 8 or above is ok, find path in preferences screen, your jvms would be in /Library/Java/VirtualMachines or something like that.

Comment: correct please it as the answer and I will approve it. I just installed the latest SDK 15 and my command line works. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anything Java 8 or above is fine.

Find path to JDK in File > Project Structure, Tab SDK Location > JDK Location.

In MacOS, installed Virtual Machines are normally placed in `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/*`